# 21.10 Show Applications Button

Tags: dock, 21.10

I just upgraded Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 and have several issues. This one has to do with the application icon on the dock launcher at the bottom of the window. I may get the exact words wrong. The first button on the bottom left of the bar consists of a 3x3 pattern of little squares. When I hover over it, the tip says "show applications". I expect when I click on it to see a grid of icons for all of the applications available.

What I see is difficult to explain, it looks more like it is being a window manager. I see two small images of my desktop background (1/4" tall x 1-1/2" long) and a white box that is probably the open Chromium application I'm using to write this bug report up.
Clicking on the white box does bring me to Chromium. Clicking on the right hand desktop image brings me to the desktop. The left hand desktop image doesn't seem to do anything.

I should have mentioned this on my first report, but yes, I've rebooted several times since the upgrade.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot, or a picture from your phone?

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` then edit your question and add the output to the bottom of your question please?

Comment: You could trying resetting your desktop settings, it seems there may be a few little issues with updates from 21.04 to 21.10. Okay open your home folder, ctrl + h to show hidden. Navigate to .config/dconf, there should be a file in there named "dconf". Right click and rename this to dconf.bak just incase you want to restore it later. Reboot your machine and see if that fixes your problem. If it doesn't you can repeat the procedure in reverse and restore your old dconf settings by first deleting the new dconf file and renaming the old back to you guessed it "dconf".